# Get dictionary values from list

Tags: python

ls=[{'value1': 'one', 'value2': 'stackoverflow'}]

how can the dictionary value from the list be printed

Desired output is:
'value2':'stackoverflow'

Thanking You.

Comment: You need to make clear an actual question. Consider rewording.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are asking is how to access dictionary elements. First, theoretically dict is a hash table and the key (value2 in your case) wouldn't exist in it's form.

If you only cared about the value, there is a syntax called subscript, internally calling dictionary's **getitem**:

```
print ls['value2']
```

Output

```
stackoverflow
```

Now, if you also want the key, the main benefit of dictionary (*constant* or in reality O(log n) lookup time) will not work for you. It is still doable with a bit of linear code though!

```
for key, value in ls:
    if key == 'value2':
        print '{}: {}'.format(key, value)
```

Output

```
value2: stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague.  But assuming you want to print the value of "value2" from a dictionary in an arbitrary length list you could do the following

```
for item in ls:
   if type(item) == dict && item.has_key("value2"):
      print item["value2"]
```